# Can I remove the title of the instagram? wordpress plugin "Instagram image gallery"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i am using wordpress plugin "Instagram image gallery". I want to remove the string of "Powered by Iconosquare" and header string "INSTAGRAMS
by @aikocunanan" any one please to help me? how to remove this string. i try to css display none method also. but no use.[image: instagram grid]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `display:none;` didn't work is because to edit an iframe's css it has to be on the same domain, in this case it isn't. Unfortunately you wouldn't be able to edit this without really digging into the plugin files. I don't recommend doing this because if an update is pushed out all of your changes will be lost.

I would recommend using this plugin by Smash Balloon, they do a great job and it will do exactly what you are looking for.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/